# Get Data Based on Row

Tags: sql-server

I have table tblControlFlag which have the data as Below.

[image: tblControlFlag]

I want to write a single query which give me the output as 1 when

```
    RRO_FLAG=1 
AND SEAL_FLAG=1 
AND TEST_CODE='VLXXXXXX' 
AND SERIAL_NO='k7jpevdt'
```

If any of the Flag value is mismatched then the query return me null.

Till now i had tried Sub Query , Exist but couldn't achieve the result.

So does it achievable , if yes then how ?

Please help me out . Thanks

Comment: your question and desired result is not clear.. do you want one result per row or one result for a set of rows/ group of rows??  If group.. what determines a group?  Serial No? don't make us assume things.. be clear as to what you want

Comment: what is the input to this query that you required ?

Comment: Is there duplicated FLAG_NAME for one SERIAL_NO?

Comment: @Harry I want one result for set of Rows. Serial Number can be used for group. To make it more clear , The FLAG_NAME and FLAG_VALUE is the Input to this query passed by application and Sorry to make you confuse.

Comment: @Squirrel Input to this Query is FLAG_NAME AND FLAG_VALUE. I want one result for set of Rows.

Comment: @qxg No, there is no duplicate FLAG for SERIAL_NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me. Not sure how you wanted the result.

Anyway,

use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING()` condition. This will returns the SERIAL_NO that matches the condition

```
select  SERIAL_NO
from    tblControlFlag
group by SERIAL_NO
HAVING   MAX(CASE WHEN FLAG_NAME = 'PRO_FLAG'  THEN FLAG_VALUE END) = '1'
AND      MAX(CASE WHEN FLAG_NAME = 'SEAL_FLAG' THEN FLAG_VALUE END) = '1'
AND      MAX(CASE WHEN FLAG_NAME = 'TESTCODE'  THEN FLAG_VALUE END) = 'VLXXXXXX'
```

or if you want the resultant column 1 or 0

```
select  SERIAL_NO,
        MATCH = CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN FLAG_NAME = 'PRO_FLAG'  THEN FLAG_VALUE END) = '1'
                     AND  MAX(CASE WHEN FLAG_NAME = 'SEAL_FLAG' THEN FLAG_VALUE END) = '1'
                     AND  MAX(CASE WHEN FLAG_NAME = 'TESTCODE'  THEN FLAG_VALUE END) = 'VLXXXXXX'
                THEN  1
                ELSE  0
                END
from    tblControlFlag
group by SERIAL_NO
```

Comment: Thanks Squirrel for your help . Your first query give me the Output as i want. I had just added the Serial_No as where condition and got the output i want. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
Select Case WHEN Count(*)>0 then 1 else null END AS TesColumn From tblControlFlag  when RRO_FLAG=1 AND SEAL_FLAG=1 AND TEST_CODE='VLXXXXXX' AND SERIAL_NO='k7jpevdt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tried sub-query and EXISTS, here is very straight-forward query but may not run fast.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SERIAL_NO)
FROM @tblControlFlag AS T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @tblControlFlag T2 WHERE T1.SERIAL_NO = T2.SERIAL_NO AND T2.FLAG_NAME = 'RRO_FLAG' AND FLAG_VALUE = '1')
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @tblControlFlag T2 WHERE T1.SERIAL_NO = T2.SERIAL_NO AND T2.FLAG_NAME = 'SEAL_FLAG' AND FLAG_VALUE = '1')
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @tblControlFlag T2 WHERE T1.SERIAL_NO = T2.SERIAL_NO AND T2.FLAG_NAME = 'TEST_CODE' AND FLAG_VALUE = 'VLXXXXXX')
```

As there is no duplicated FLAG_NAME per SERIAL_NO, you could convert row to columns and perform the check `RRO_FLAG=1 AND SEAL_FLAG=1 AND TEST_CODE='VLXXXXXX' AND SERIAL_NO='k7jpevdt'`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM @tblControlFlag
) AS T
PIVOT (
    MAX(FLAG_VALUE) FOR FLAG_NAME IN (RRO_FLAG, [SEAL_FLAG], [TEST_CODE])
) AS P
WHERE RRO_FLAG=1 AND SEAL_FLAG=1 AND TEST_CODE='VLXXXXXX' AND SERIAL_NO='k7jpevdt'
```